# How to put a comma between arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Here is a code...

```
<div id="d1">
 <ol>
  <li id="li1"></li>
  <li id="li2"></li>
 </ol>
<div>

 <script>
   var dod = document.getElementById("d1");
   var foo = dod.getElementsByTagName("*");

    for(i=0;i<foo.length;i++){
       console.log(foo[i].id);
       }
 </script>
```

How can I put commas between Id's?

Comment: You mean like this `console.log(foo[i].id + (i < foo.length-1)? ", " : "");`?

Comment: @JCOC611: The higher precedence of `+` will require a set of parens around the conditional operator. `console.log(foo[i].id + (i < foo.length-1 ? ", " : ""));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way would be this:

```
var separator = ", ";
for(i=0;i<foo.length;i++){
   if(i == foo.length - 1) {
      separator = "";
   }

   console.log(foo[i].id + separator);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Let's have some fun:

```
console.log(Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll("#d1 *"), function(e) {
    return e.id;
}).join(", "));
```

This was originally meant to be a bit of a joke, but it has a core of seriousness to it and demonstrates some handy things:

- `document.querySelectorAll` will give you a (disconnected) `NodeList` of elements matching a CSS selector. So `#d1 *` gives us all of the descendant elements of `#d1`.
- `Array.prototype.map` is happy to be used on anything array-like, it doesn't require that you use it on an actual array.
- `Function#call` lets you call a function and tell it what `this` during the function call should be. So `Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll("#d1 *"), ...` calls `map` making it use the `NodeList` from `querySelectorAll` as `this`.
- `Array.prototype.map` calls the function you give it once for each "array" element, passing in the element, and building a new array from what you return. So our callback that returns `e.id` tells it to build an array of `id` values.
- `Array.prototype.join` builds a string from the array elements, using the string you give it as the separator between them.

...and you know from your own code that `console.log` outputs it.

But looking at your HTML, we need to tweak it to only elements that actually have `id` values, or we'll end up with a lot of blanks in the result. That's easily done, we just add `filter`:

```
console.log(Array.prototype.filter.call(document.querySelectorAll("#d1 [id]"), function(e) {
    return e.id !== "";
}).map(function(e) { return e.id; }).join(", "));
```

Two changes there:

- I used `#d1 [id]` for the selector so we only got back elements with an`id` attribute.
- I added a call to `.filter` before `.map` to filter out elements that have an `id` attribute, but with a blank value (sadly, no way to filter those out in CSS, e.g., defending against `<li id="">`).

[Example](http://jsbin.com/guqah/1)

Comment: TJ, you might need to comment some of this code. `Array.prototype.map.call` for example.

Comment: @Andy: I guess I will. It was actually meant to be a joke, but then it got upvoted, so...

Comment: That'll teach you to be cocky :)

Comment: +1 for the commentary.

Comment: FWIW, the filter can be handled by `qSA`, like so: `"#d1 [id]:not([id=''])"`

Comment: @cookiemonster: That blows up IE8 support, and is defeated by `id=" "`. (I've corrected the above to allow for the latter invalid HTML.)*

Comment: Good point about IE8. WRT space-only IDs, that would seem to be a problem that should be fixed, but I get what you're saying. I don't know that removing all spaces would be best though since it could result in some false positives if there are some funky IDs, like if there are elements with `id="foobar"` and `id="foo bar"`. But it's hard to know the best way to deal with invalid stuff.

Comment: @cookiemonster: My regex was **awful**, thanks for the very subtle and gentle poke. `id` values aren't allowed to have `spaces`, but what I was doing was Just Wrong.